# How to display posts list on my plugin page?

Tags: plugin-development

Currently, I makes a plugin, and I want to display some post in admin submenu, my url looks like

wp-admin/admin.php?page=mypluginpage

how to display posts list on my plugin page? it's possible or not?

Thanks.

---

Please delete this post, I just found solution:

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    )
);

$list = array();
foreach ($query->posts as $post) {
    .......
}
?>
```

Comment: Instead of deleting you can just write your solution in an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Better would be the use of WordPress' function get_posts():

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );

echo '<ul>';

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    echo '<li>' . $post->post_title . '</li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts